# Move single word lines to different file and delete the line in file using Korn shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

I have the below file, where the names (single word) are to be moved to a different file stored as U1 and delete that line. In the same file have to pick the name from a line stored as M1. file 1:

```
    Alter user Scott account lock;
    Tim
    Alter user David account lock;
    Tim
    Alter user Jennifer account lock;
    Samantha
    Alter user Ethan account lock;
    Richard
```

File 1 turnout: (single words are deleted, after moving to file2)

```
    Alter user Scott account lock;
    Alter user David account lock;
    Alter user Jennifer account lock;
    Alter user Ethan account lock;
```

File 2: (all names stored as M1 to be used later)

```
    Tim
    Tim
    Samantha
    Richard
```

I can do awk '{print $3}' on file 1 to get the names and store them as U1 to be used later. so they are, file 3

```
    Scott
    David
    Jennifer
    Ethan
```

I'll use the above names from M1 and U1 to use them in mailx to send mail to users (u1) and their managers (M1).

```
    mailx -s "User account U1 expired" "M1@xyz.com U1@.xyz.com"
```

that goes for all users like

Separated the names from output file and created file 3.

as given above

1. mailx -s "User Account Scott expired" "tim@xyz.com scott@xyz.com"
2. mailx -s "User Account David expired" "tim@xyz.com david@xyz.com"

My challenges:

1. How to delete single names from file 1?
2. how to input file 2 (M1)and file 3 (U1) into mailx

Comment: challenge 3. Match user and manager? I don't see any information that helps with that. Hopefully not just the sequence in file 1 or matching file1/line1 with file2/line1 (yikes!)? You can delete single names with `sed '!/.* .*/d' file1`. Good luck.

Comment: That's correct 'Shellter" on Challenge 3. Also for mapping it goes in the given order.                                                                                                                            Tim               -      Scott                                                                                                                 Tim               -      David
Samantha     -      Jennifer
Richard         -      Ethan    ---- When I try the above sed: I get the error "sed: 0602-403 !/.* .*/d is not a recognized function." Am I missing anything.

Comment: Is this a simplified version of a real world problem you are facing? If so, you'll do better to redesign the process. If school work or other learning, the only thing I can think of is to store input as arrays (with a separate array to track line number) and then cycle thru arrays as needed to generate the data you want. I would call this a non-trivial problem and won't be able to spend time on it. Good luck.

Comment: Its real world problem that I have to complete as enhancement for full automation. As of now we have scripts that sends user lock status to all users, but their managers also need to be informed so it will be easy for escalations when user fails to take action. We have a reference table in oracle that maps users and managers. Current scripts picks up the user only and his manager have to be added to the mailx command to send to user and manager is my enhancement project to be implemented. Any tips/assistance towards this is appreciated.

Comment: Just shooting from the hip here, but I would try to do as much of this rk in a database as possible. While I haven't used oracle much, I would think given all the features they have crammed into their products that it should be easy to send email from inside the DB. AND I would just filter that first tile down to a list of names (and timestamps, other relevant info (system, db, etc) ) load into a table and send emails after joining to manager name.  I don't think you want a bunch of (relatively) tiny files lying around that you have to manage. Get it all into a db and manger it there. GoodLuck

Comment: You can use `grep "^ALTER"` and `grep -v "^ALTER"` for the first challenge. The second one can be used `grep -i -A1 ALTER` when your grep supports this. Alternatives are (good) `awk` and (possible) a while-loop. Did you notice the error? `grep -i -A1 ALTER` will also find `Walter`, so match at the beginning of the line.
Can you change the way that you generate `expired_users.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code takes your File1 as its parameter then create File2.txt and send the mail. The other files are not created since the mail is already sent.

```
#!/bin/ksh

FileToProcess=$1

while read line; do
        ((i++))
        Arr[$i].FullLine="$line"
        Arr[$i].LineParts=( $line )
done < $FileToProcess

for j in ${!Arr[@]}; do
        if [[ ${#Arr[$j].LineParts[@]} -gt 1 ]]; then
                print ${Arr[$j].FullLine} >> ./File2.txt
                mailx -s "User Account ${Arr[$j].LineParts[2]} expired" "${Arr[$((j+1))].FullLine}@xyz.com ${Arr[$j].LineParts[2]}@xyz.com"
        fi
done
```

Hope it helps

Andre Gelinas

Comment: Appreciate your script. When I run the code I get the error,  "0403-057 Syntax error at line 12 : `(' is not expected."

Comment: I don't see any "(" in the line 12....I've copy/pasted directly from this page..no syntax error on mine. Using ksh 93u+ on my server...maybe a versionning problem ?